# Creating Pairplot graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create a pairplot on my data. Unfortunetly I constantly get errors, I have tried to do it this way:

```
cons1 = pd.DataFrame(cons columns=cons.columns)
sns.pairplot(cons1[['Team', 'Point']])
```

Error:

```
"None of [Index(['Team', 'Point'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

second try:

```
sns.pairplot(cons, kind='reg')
```

Error:

```
'data' must be pandas DataFrame object, not: <class 'list'>
```

Kindly request, Can somebody help me to understand how can I correctly use pairplot?

This is how my table looks

[image: My Table]

Comment: Please add your data as text, not as image.  Please clarify what's exactly in the variable `cons`.  Your first example is also missing a comma and doesn't make sense if `cons` is already a dataframe. The error message of your second examples tells that `cons` is a `list`, not a dataframe (therefore, your first example should generate another error).  Please add more information.  Note that the column `Team` can't be used in a pairplot, as it is only meant for numeric columns.

Comment: OK, so "cons" is the data cons = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/fia-f1-19502019-data/constructors_championship_1958-2020.csv') that you can see on the screen ok, so  it should work if I take two numeric columns?